# Qthread deleteLater() crashing program

Tags: c++, qt, segmentation-fault, qthread, qeventloop

QT 4.8: I have been getting a number of segment faults and I/O Possible errors in my code that I cannot figure out. From print statements I have seen a number of odd and inconsistent behaviors, likely indicating race conditions. Many times everything works perfect. Sometimes I get an I/O error immediately after the worker destructor is called, indicating main connect deleteLater() issue. Other times if I try to delete audioOutput in destructor it will work a number of times then give me a segment fault (or I/O) randomly in middle of destructor on other attempts. I believe my issues can be attributed to 2 things, worker cleanup/ connect quit()/deletelater() calls and my recursive loop in worker which needs to create its own event loop every time thus possibly emitting finished signal before the previous calls can be cleaned up?

Specifically my questions are:

What could cause deleteLater() to create an I/O Possible error?

how should I delete pointers inside of worker class so they are deleted at the correct time (end)... or does QT handle this for me?

Gui and .h

```
QByteArray* qbyte;
QThread* thread;
PlayAudio* audioWorker;

MainWindow::startSound()
{
    QFile soundFile;
    soundFile.setFileName("/home/sounds/sound.wav");
    qbyte = new  QByteArray(soundFile.readAll());
    soundFile.close();
    thread= new QThread;
    audioWorker= new PlayAudio(qbyte, 5);
    audioWorker->moveToThread(thread);
    connect(thread, SIGNAL(started()), audioWorker, SLOT(play()));
    connect(audioWorker, SIGNAL(finished()), thread, SLOT(quit()));
    connect(audioWorker, SIGNAL(finished()), audioWorker,SLOT(deleteLater()));
    connect(thread, SIGNAL(finished()), thread, SLOT(deleteLater()));
    connect(thread, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(donePlaying()));
}
MainWindow::donePlaying()
{
    //do stuff
}
```

Worker class and .h

```
QByteArray qbyte;
int numOfPlays;
int numOfPlaysRun;
bool quit = false;
QBuffer *qbuff;
QAudioFormat format;
QAudioOutput *audioOutput;

PlayAudio::PlayAudio(QByteArray *qbyte_, int num)
{
    qbyte=*qbyte_;
    numOfPlays=num;
    qbuff=new QBuffer();
    qbuff->setData(qbyte);
    qbuff->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly); 
       //set format
    audioOutput  = new QAudioOutput(format,this);  
    connect(audioOutput,SIGNAL(stateChanged(QAudio::State)),
                           SLOT(finishedPlaying(QAudio::State)));
}

void PlayAudio::::play()
{
    if (!quit)
    {
        audioOutput->start(qbuff);
        QEventLoop loop;
        do {
            loop.exec();            
        } while(!quit);
    }
}

 void PlayAudio::finishedPlaying(QAudio::State state)
{
    if (state == QAudio::IdleState)
    {
        if (numOfPlaysRun< numOfPlays && !quit)
        {
            numOfPlaysRun++;
            play();
        }
        else
        {
            //should i ever stop loop myself? or is that done from main?
            //quit=true;
            emit finished();
        }
    }
}
PlayAudio:: ~PlayAudio()
{
    // still have  qbuff and audioOutput to delete. If i do here i sometimes            
    //get segment faults or IO error.
}
```

---

updated:

still have intermittent issues but commenting out the following line has helped clear some of them in combination with setting quit=true.

```
connect(audioWorker, SIGNAL(finished()), audioWorker,SLOT(deleteLater()));
```

But this may cause a memory leak?

---

Update 2:

I'm starting to think I'm talking to myself here but I think I got it. It appears this was a timing issue as the thread was returning finished() prior to the worker actually finishing due to the time to unwind from quit() signal that closes the open loops once the worker emits finished(). So I now emit a custom signal from worker for every loop closed and track this in main. Once I receive what I expect I then release wait() and delete the thread THEN then worker. Not sure if this is correct but it seems to be working. Seems hackish to me but IMO the thread shouldn't return finished until the worker does, seems pointless then. but oh well.

Comment: May be you can post the solution as answer for others to follow later if they face similar issue.

Comment: Note that `deleteLater()` doesn't guarantee a determinable time behaviour, you should use it with care, if ever. Better use scoped pointers or similar, depending on the scenario.